# Handling "More" button in tripadvisor while scraping data using r

Tags: r

I am using this code to extract data from trip advisor.

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
install.packages("xmlparsedata")
library(xmlparsedata)
install.packages("xml2")
library(xml2)
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)

url.1 <- "https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Restaurant_Review-g186605-d4046860- 
Reviews-The_Stage_Door_Cafe-Dublin_County_Dublin.html"

reviews <- url.1 %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

id <- reviews %>%
html_node(".quote a") %>%
html_attr("id")

quote <- reviews %>%
html_node(".quote span") %>%
html_text()

rating <- reviews %>%
html_node(".rating .rating.bubble") %>%
html_attr("alt") %>%
gsub(" of 5 stars", "", .) %>%
as.integer()

date <- reviews %>%
html_node(".ratingDate .relativeDate") %>%
html_attr("title") %>%
strptime("%b %d, %Y") %>%
as.POSIXct()

review <- reviews %>%
html_node(".entry .partial_entry" ) %>%
html_text()

a.1 <- data.frame(id, quote, rating, date, review, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The problem i am facing here is the 'more' button in the reviews, i am not able to click it using the Rselenium package as it is archived from R.

```
install.packages("seleniumPipes")
library(seleniumPipes)
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
ra <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rappdirs/rappdirs_0.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(ra, repos=NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
library(rappdirs)
sem <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/semver/semver_0.1.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(sem, repos=NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
library(semver)
bin <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/binman/binman_0.0.7.tar.gz"
install.packages(bin, repos=NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
library(binman)
sub <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/subprocess_0.8.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(sub, repos=NULL, type="source")
library(subprocess)
wd <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/wdman/wdman_0.2.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(wd, repos=NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
library(wdman)
packageurl <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RSelenium/RSelenium_1.6.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
library(RSelenium)
```

i have manually tried to instally all the archived packages but all in vain, not able to start selenium. I also have tried with installing selenium with docker but no luck.

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.43.66",
+                                  port = 4444L,
+                                  browserName = "phantomjs")
```

Succedeed with this but when i enter

> remDr$open()
>   getting the following error.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVnWq.png) "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to 10.3.100.207 port 4444: Network unreachable

Is there any other workaround to click the 'more' button using the rvest package?  as this RSelenium is kind of obselete.

This is the screenshot link for the 'more' button

[image]